# XCode 4.5 - Error on libxml2

Tags: xcode, libxml2

I have an app that I was compiling normally, but when I updated my XCode to version 4.5, it started complaining about libxml2.

The problem is in this line:

```
typedef void *(LIBXML_ATTR_ALLOC_SIZE(1) XMLCALL *xmlMallocFunc)(size_t size);
```

Errors:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:66:39: Expected parameter declarator
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:66:39: Expected ')'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:66:50: Expected ')'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:66:38: Function cannot return function type 'void *(size_t)'
```

Is anyone facing this same problem?

Regards!

Comment: yeah, me too, hopefully someone can advice.

Comment: buddy, I fixed it but don't remember how! As soon as I remember I will answer here! Really sorry